# ASIHTTPRequest Redirection Limit

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest

Is it advise-able to adjust the RedirectionLimit in ASIHTTPRequest.m?

Why is it a constant and not adjustable (or is it)?

Comment: 5 redirects appears to be an arbitrary, hard-coded number. That said, how many redirects does one really need? According to a comment in the project's source code: "// Some naughty / badly coded website is trying to force us into a redirection loop. This is not cool."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no other way to make your application work, it's fine to change the limit.

If you are in control of the server and can reduce the number of redirections required that would be the prefered solution, as each redirection will cause a delay in the device receiving the data it's trying to get for the user.

There isn't an API to change it, just adjust the value in ASIHTTPRequest.m, RedirectionLimit near the top of the file.